# Control System 4 with just a keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard, classic-mac-os

Is there a reference of keyboard shortcuts for System 4, so I can use a Macintosh SE with a keyboard and no mouse?

I found a Macintosh SE and a keyboard on the street several years ago. It didn't have any cables, so the only thing I could do with the Mac was use another power cable and turn it on. Yesterday, my ADB cable arrived, so I can use the keyboard, but I still don't have a compatible mouse. According to my Googling, the Macintosh SE runs System 4 and Finder 5.2.

Is there a reference of keyboard shortcuts for System 4, so I can play around with the system?

Answer (score 2):

While it is reasonably possible to use a classic Mac without a *keyboard*, using one without a mouse requires a System software disk with the **Easy Access** control panel installed.

With **Easy Access** installed, you can press **Command-Shift-Clear** to toggle **Mouse Keys** at which point your numeric keypad can be used to control the mouse cursor and the computer will be frustrating, but functional.

A limited number of shortcuts are still documented on Apple's site in [Archived Technical Note 28141](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta28141). Also, you can select icons in open windows by typing the first letters of the icon's name (for example, 'sys' will select "System Folder"), followed by **Command-O** to open.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there aren't enough keyboard shortcuts (apart from your copy and paste, etc.) that'd allow you to play with the OS too much.
I also couldn't find a reference - things like this are surprisingly scarce.

I did find a Macintosh ADB mouse from [here](http://compare.ebay.co.uk/like/400362414861?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar&cbt=y) though - if you're alright with eBay or things like that.